# MaterializeCss changes all input field IDs

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, material-design, materialize

Something really peculiar is happening and I can't figure out why.
I'm using materializecss framework for my UI. But for some reason when I'm including any input fields in my HTML like

```
<div class="col s5">
    <input id="teacher_id" runat="server" type="number" placeholder="Your ID"/>
</div>
```

the id and the names are getting changed to some jibberish like

```
<div class="col s5">
    <input name="**ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$teacher_id**" type="number" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_teacher_id" placeholder="Your ID">
</div>
```

Can someone please help? What am I doing wrong?

(I'm using Asp.net with a master page)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out.
It wasn't materializecss but insteas asp.net itself.
To refer to the fields from jquery or js i used the following:

```
$('#<%= teacher_id.ClientID %>').val('123');
```

Didn't exactly solve the issue, but the workaround calmed some of the concerns ..for now.